# How to get new AMDGPU driver in Opensuse?

Tags: opensuse, gpu, amd-graphics

I have OpenSUSE 42.1 kde 5. How to get the new AMDGPU driver (in the website its only released for ubuntu with .deb files)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMDGPU consists of a device driver which is part of Linux since 4.3 and a XOrg driver, which you're both currently missing. If you want to use AMDGPU, you'll need to upgrade your kernel (use [this](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Kernel:/stable/standard/) repository) and your XOrg using [this](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/X11:/XOrg/openSUSE_Leap_42.1/) repository. Afterwards do a vendor change for all packages in the repositories. You can now install xf86-video-amdgpu.

*Careful, you will replacing core system components with new versions that haven't been tested on your distribution version. Don't do this if you have no way to recover a non-working X11.*